# how to use ASP.NET api in android

Tags: android, asp.net

I m using android to call asp.net api, but i dont know how to do this.
required Request and Response is attached below:

api link is like :

```
http://gateway.xxx.xxx.com.np/websrv/Service.asmx
```

Request is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <UserLists xmlns="xxx">
        <Id>string</Id>    
        <UserName>string</UserName>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <Datetime>string</Datetime>
        <Signature>string</Signature>
    </UserLists>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <UserListsResponse xmlns="xxx">
        <UserListsResult>
            <UserLists>
                <Name>string</Name>
                <Code1>string</Code1>
                <CODE2>string</CODE2>
                <MESSAGE>string</MESSAGE>
            </UserLists>
            <UserLists>
                <Name>string</Name>  
                <Code1>string</Code1>
                <CODE2>string</CODE2>
                <MESSAGE>string</MESSAGE>
             </UserLists>
         </UserListsResult>
    </UserListsResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I've spend too much time to study other online tutorials but did not get any clear understanding and useful solution. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is just XML. Create XML request, parse XML response

Comment: ok i'll try this sir

Comment: simple xml parser is not work for me sir...

Comment: the n you likely did something wrong.

Comment: actually xmp parser response the string same like above. but i need value of those parameters...

Comment: i have a api url like above can u check this one please

Comment: which values you need?

Comment: the value that api targets. Above request and reponse data is the sample of data looks like. I dont know how to use this api to retrieve data

Comment: As I saird, make a regullar request with the XML data passed as String. The response String is also XML data, which you can parse with any XML parser. Be more specific on what excatly is a problem for you.